# Umbraco & different publishing channels

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We want to use umbraco to manage content for another application. The application shows a newsfeed and the associated newsitem details.

So, when adding newsitem content to umbraco I want 3 separate buttons ... "Save", "Publish to App" and "Publish to web". It would be nice to add the buttons to the content editing screens.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Need some guidance here, as an alternative i could build an entire new sections to manage the newsitem publication ... but it seems a lot more work.

Thanks

Comment: Adding a third button to the Umbraco backend would be very difficult, I believe :-s

What if you added a checkbox on each newsitem to determine whether it should be shown in your app, and then somehow sent along a parameter to your different views?

Comment: I could do that but then I would have to determine to which channels the content is already published ... when publishing on different times

Comment: Well, yes, if you intend to use timed publishing even three buttons wouldn't help? Otherwise, if a document is published and "Show in app" is set to true, it would show in app. If a document is published and "Show in app" is NOT set to true, you can prevent it from being shown in the view. Maybe I'm not getting what the issue is, sorry...

Comment: No, you're getting it ;-) I'll look into it, thanks for the suggestions